# Add a property to the entity that is not a column and that can contain an HTTP request value

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, post, spring-data-jpa

I have a User entity that has as many properties as there are columns in the database and a transient one next to that. The user can be part of an Organisation, which is a onetoone relationship. In that entity the data type is an Organisation object.

The model is also used in the controller to check and contain the request data values, but this cannot be achieved with organisation, because the user passes the name as a string and in the entity, the organisation is an object as already mentioned.

So I would like to add another property that can contain the organisation name, so then I can convert it to an Organisation object in the Service. But I can't add a regular property because Spring JPA will think it should be a column and it can't be a transient property either, because it's ignored on the controller side for the request.

Currently I'm achieving this by adding another parameter with `@RequestParam(name="organisationname")`, and passing it together with the User object to the Service, but I have the feeling that this is not the proper way.

How can I approach this differently and in the User entity itself?

Comment: Perhaps you can add a header as parameter @RequestHeader("organizationname") String orgName, I saw several APIs, for example Google, Zoho that put orgId is passed as header.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your JSON serializer NOT ignore `@Transient` fields (I like this approach as transient is a DB term so it shouldn't be affecting your JSON serialization) - you can then use `@JsonIgnore` to skip JSON serialization properties.

So `@Transient` to ignore when interacting with the DB, `@JsonIgnore` to ignore when serializing/deserializing.

If using the Jackson ObjectMapper you can do the following:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
    hibernate5Module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    mapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module);
    return mapper;
}
```